# Detect timeout on Windows and Linux with Libssh

Tags: libssh

In the testing I'm doing I have noticed that (both with blocking mode):
On Linux `ssh_channel_read_timeout` when command timeout answer 0 (readBytes).
On Windows `ssh_channel_read_timeout` when command timeout answer -1 (readBytes).
Both call the same function `ssh_channel_read_timeout`.

Also:
On Linux `ssh_channel_is_eof` answer `false` when command timeout.
On Windows `ssh_channel_is_eof` answer `true` when command timeout.

Any hint about this different behavior ?
Or is there any effective way to detect when a timeout has been triggered ?
The command that is executed is very simple: `sleep 1 | free -m`

Comment: The ssh server run on Linux. And i test the command ```sleep 1 | free -m``` from Windows and other Linux client.